# How to fix iOS error -9813 and -9802?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue to make an investigation using my iOS app (iOS 9.3.3). I need to connect to a site which uses self-signed certificate. That site redirects me to an address with http. I see several solutions, but neither of them is working.

First I try to disable the `https` check using `NSAppTransportSecurity` but I still get -9813. I add domain as exception using `NSExceptionDomains` but still continue to receive that error.

Comment: you need to install and trust the certificate on the device

Comment: Ok, @Wain, but how? Can you give me a clue? Also in 9.3.3 I try only http request with solution to disable security, but I still get -9813?

Comment: e-mail yourself the cert and open the attachment

Comment: Ok, @Wain, but what about `http` requests?

Comment: if you're using http and still getting -9813 then there must be a redirection somewhere

Comment: Sorry, @Wain, but it is still not working. Added exceptions for 2 domains (1st with certificate and 2nd with http). I downloaded certificate and send it to my iPhone. I installed it as new profile. And after that I still receive -9813.

Comment: did you check the cert you installed is trusted

Comment: No, @Wain. How? I only see that the profile is installed. I open the same page in Safari and it gives me report that the certificate is not trusted. I agree to use it and then the page is opened ok. My problem is that when I try to open the same page in `UIWebView` I get -9813. I thought that when I install certificate it will be trusted after that?

Comment: Ok @Wain, I find profiles. There is only remark that the certificate is not verified.  It this means that it is trusted?

Comment: you install it and you get an option to trust, or sometimes you don't, i'm not sure why in all cases, probably something about the trust chain validity i guess - accepting in safari is just for safari, if the cert isn't trusted by the device you can't use it in your app - your only other option would be SSL pinning / URL connection delegation to force validate the untrusted cert

Comment: 10x a lot for your time. I will try to use your last advice, @Wain. May be I did not exported it properly. I try again. The procedure is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If your site runs on Http// then you have to add an `App Transport Security Settings` 
Under that `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES`.
If Your site runs on Https// then there no need to add any Key to your info.plist file.
Hope This will help you . If not let me know.

Comment: I know that. The problem is that `https` certificate is self-signed. And I get `-9813`.

Comment: Then you have to authorize your certificate first(Sign it). I don't think there a way for it.

Comment: Yes, I have to import it. Which is not good for me, but that is the way. 10x for answer